# What are some of Masamune Shirow's most recent works?

Tags: mangaka

Is Masamune Shirow working on any kind of manga?

I'm still waiting for an end for Appleseed and I won't mind to see something like a new Orion or Tank Police Dominion.

Comment: The appleseed manga ended a long time ago already right ? " Original run  February 15, 1985 – April 15, 1989"

Comment: the story doesn't really end with the forth volume

Comment: Rumors of a possible Volume 5 still persist today, though Shirow had mentioned that he has no plans of pursuing it for the meantime. Guess this means it is sort of on hiatus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

His [work chronology](http://www.shirowledge.com/index_enu.html#comic) listed on his official website, shows some of his recent works, and plans for near future. He doesn't seem to have any plans for the series you mentioned.

```
2013/09/11  SEVEN TRAPS : Auto fighter-bomber SUZUMEBACHI (Hornet) (Monthly YOUNG MAGAZINE)
2013/09/20  INTRON DEPOT 6 BARB WIRE 01 (Art Book)
2013/09/27  W-TAILS CAT - A STRANGE PRESENCE - Episode 06 (Stream)
2013/10/09  SEVEN TRAPS : Multipurpose multi-legged tank unit HONOOARI (Flame Ant) (Monthly YOUNG MAGAZINE)
2013/10/10  Cover Girl Fragments Vol.7 (comic Anthurium 007) 
2013/10/25  W-TAILS CAT - A STRANGE PRESENCE - Episode 07 (Stream)
2013/11/09  Cover Girl Fragments Vol.8 (comic Anthurium 008)
2013/11/xx  INTRON DEPOT 7 BARB WIRE 02 (Art Book)
2013/11/30  Ghost In The Shell ARISE border:2 Ghost Whispers (Movie)
2013/11/30  Shirow Masamune Calendar SABER TOOTH CATS 6 (Calendar)
2014/01/xx  GREASE BERRIES 1 (Art Book)
```

Comment: not good, I like how he draws, but even more I liked the stories he was telling in his mangas